# With timeout never fires Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

Hey so I am trying to add a timeout to my request but it never fires here's how I am calling the suspend fun :

```
                getSettingJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    getSettings(this@MainActivity)
                }
```

and here is the actual function :

```
    suspend fun getSettings(context: Context?) {
      Timber.i("  Request started ")
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).async(Dispatchers.Main) {
        try {
            withTimeout(120000L) {... do stuff}
        }catch(ex : TimeoutCancellationException) {
          ... show error message
        }

      }.await()
 }
```

I am not getting any errors the timeout just never fires, does it have something to do with the fact that the job is launched on IO and the coroutine scope is Main or something with async await ? both say they are cancellable so not sure that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

> Coroutine cancellation is cooperative.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

If the coroutine does not reach a suspension point (e.g. if the thread is blocked), it won't be cancelled.

---

For the cancellation signal to reach a coroutine with a blocked thread, use `runInterruptible`.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html

---

```
// this doesn't throw
withTimeout(100) {
    Thread.sleep(500)
}
println("slept")

// this throws
withTimeout(100) {
    runInterruptible { Thread.sleep(500) }
}
```